# Why Dasein has only a pre-ontological Being rather than an ontological Being?

Tags: heidegger, phenomenology, being-and-time

In the book Being and Time, Heidegger wrote that:

> We have already intimated that Dasein has a pre-ontological Being as
>   its ontically constitutive state.

It's intuitive to me only when I thought it is because Dasein is limited in time and energy to have an ontological one. If I am wrong, what is the reason to state that?

Comment: "Pre-ontological Being" is an oxymoron.

Comment: @EternalPropagation - I think Heidegger was meaning unmanifest and prior to the distinction we make between existence and non-existence. If so then his comment is standard stuff for the Perennial philosophy, albeit perhaps rather clumsily put. This is not to endorse it. He is still hanging on to the Beng/nonBeing distinction.   .